# JDBC Driver Not Found error in Crystal Reports

Tags: jdbc, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports 2013. Using Informix JDBC driver `ifxjdbc.jar`. Report was working before.

Situation:

1. `CRConfig.xml` was edited so following was in Classpath:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java/lib/ifxjdbc.jar
   ```

   and connection info edited:

   ```
   <JDBCURL>jdbc:informix-sqli://xxx.yyy.local:50001/xxx:informixserver=xxx_ol</JDBCURL>
   <JDBCClassName>com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver</JDBCClassName>
   <JDBCUserName>billy</JDBCUserName>
   ```
2. `ifxjdbc.jar` placed in the above directory listed in (1).

I get the error

> JDBC driver not found

Why do I get this error?

I entered the path above like in the other entries--I also tried putting the `ifxjdbc.jar` in a simple directory like `c:\myfolder\ifxjdbc.jar`, and entering it just like that in the CLASSPATH. No joy.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either the path is wrong, and you're assuming incorrectly, OR the class name is incorrect.

That path could be a problem because it has spaces in it.  Did you surround it with double quotes to let the JVM know that is shouldn't stop reading between "Program" and "Files"?

Answer (score 0):

Customer had saved ifxjdbc.jar as ifxjdbc.jar.txt . File extension visibility was turned off in Windows, so looked like ifxjdbc.jar. So it was read as a text file. D'oh!

Works fine now.